# Azure Portal account creation, use @xyz.onmicrosoft.com or @xyz.com?

Tags: azure

I have an SharePoint Office 365 Developer account and initially it was created using @xyz.onmicrosoft.com account.

Now I have added @xyz.com. All the billing management happen using the admin@xyz.onmicrosoft.com and application access happen using user@xyz.com

Now I am planning to add Azure Pay-As-You-Go subscription but I am confused should I create the Azure portal account using admin@xyz.onmicrosoft.com or user@xyz.com

Is there any best practice or general recommendation available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is completely up to your organization, there are no major advantages of using one or other.

Nevertheless,  an "user@xyz.com" account will be friendlier than "user@xyz.onmicrosoft.com".